# Magento : How to get selected bundle option title and value from bundle product?

Tags: php, jquery, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to get selected bundle option title and value on product detail page.

**Unit Colour* : Antelope Audio Zodiac Digital to Anologue Converter   +£0.00**

I use the below code but it return me option list and not selected option value but not title like **Unit color**

```
$bundled_product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $bundled_product->load($_product->getId());
    $selectionCollection = $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
        $bundled_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($bundled_product), $bundled_product
    );
    $bundled_items = array();
    foreach($selectionCollection as $option)
    {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($option);die;
        $bundled_items[] = $option->product_id;
    }
```

Please check below image also.
[image]

So please suggest me idea how can i get title and selected value.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: this snippet works fine with the bundle product on magento demo site:
http://demo.magentocommerce.com/my-computer.html

If I put into browser URL bar the below snippet with prefix `javascript:` and postfix `generate_options_label_and_value()`, it works fine for the radio buttons. If you need more extended case (supporting dropdowns/checkboxes), let me know. This is just a quick snippet:

```
function generate_options_label_and_value(){ 
    var generated_html = '';
    $$("#product-options-wrapper>dl>dt").each( function (dt){ 
        if(dt.next('dd').select('input:checked[type=radio]').length > 0 ){
            generated_html += dt.select("label")[0].innerHTML;
            generated_html += dt.next('dd').select('input:checked[type=radio]')[0].next('span').innerHTML;
        }
    });
    if(!$('selected_options_div')){
        $$('.add-to-cart')[0].insert({ top : "<div id='selected_options_div'></div>"});
    }
    $('selected_options_div').update(generated_html);
}
```

This is written in prototype